# can I use setInterval in the definition of a javascript "class"?

Tags: javascript

I would like to start a `setInterval` method in javascript every time I instantiate a class (I know, I shouldn't call it class in javascript, ...). The `setInterval` is calling the class method `update` every 500 milliseconds. Here is my code:

```
function Test(a) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = 0;
  this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 500);
};

Test.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log(this.b);
    this.b += 1;
    if (this.b > 10) clearInterval(this.interval);
};
```

But when I instantiate the class with `var mytest = new Test(1)`, the class property `b` seems to be undefined in the first call and NaN subsequently (because adding 1 to undefined gives NaN). Why `b` is not `0`in the first call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of `this` changes when setInterval fires. `this` will be `window`. To maintain the scope, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 500);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works nicely.